# How to get which edge of two rectangles are colliding

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I have an ALMOST working physics system. When two objects collide, each will have it's OnCollide function called so that it may properly react to the collision.

My issue comes into handling collisions properly for both x AND y. I know that an edge of a rectangle can only collide with one edge of the other rectangle. However, I don't know the math to determine which edge it is.

So how would I tell rectangle 1 which edge rectangle 2 collided with knowing only the x,y,height,and width of each rectangle?

(I'm working in c# by the way)

Comment: Can the rectangles rotate ? If not, Xa < Xb and Xa + Wa > Xb + Wb tell you if the rectangle A has at least a point to the left (respectively right) of B. Similarly for Y.

Comment: They can't rotate, but since it's a real time collision engine, it checks collision once the rectangles have overlapped. So if it's colliding, it will be at least slightly inside both axis.

Comment: The solution lies in my previous comment. Beware of the cases such that a rectangle is wholly inside another.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of trial and error, I was able to discover a solution.

First, you check which axis the collision is happening "the most" on. Once you've determined that, you simply compare the values on that axis to see which direction it's happening. The following psudocode should do nicely when translated into the language of your choice.

```
if absoluteValue(box1.y - box2.y) > absoluteValue(box1.x - box2.x)
   if box1.y > box2.y
    box 1 is collding with the top of box 2
    else
        box 1 is colliding with the bottom of box 2
else
   if box1.x < box2.x
    box 1 is collding with the left of box 2
    else
    box 1 is collding with the right of box 2
```

This doesn't take the boxes height and width into account, but I don't think that should be a problem in most cases. Though you may run into issues dealing with rectangles with largely different sizes in their axis.